# disable DeviceOrientationNotification as long as calculation is running

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, device-orientation

my app is doing calculations and showing the results in a graph. When the device is rotating a new `UIViewController` is generated showing the graph in a landscape-oriented view. Therefore necessary parameters are passed to the new ViewController to create the graph.
The app is crashing when the device is turned to landscape when the calculation is still running.

Is there a proper way to disable the used `DeviceOrientationNotification` temporarily?

```
-(void)calculate
{

disable DeviceOrientationNotification

...calculation code here

enable DeviceOrientationNotification again

}
```

Thanks
(don't beat me up again, even if the question appears to be stupid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 5 and 6 there is a call back on UIViewcontrollers for autorotation. I would just set a flag when you start your calculation that you shouldn't autorotate and set it back when you are done.

```
//somewhere in .h or class extension or simple member variable
@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldRotate;

// iOS 6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return self.shouldRotate;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;//Return what is supported
}

// pre-iOS 6 support
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

    return self.shouldRotate && //other interface check;
}

-(void)calculate{
     self.shouldRotate = NO;
     //do calculation
     self.shouldRotate = YES;
}
```

Comment: It took me a while cause I had to figure out to put the flag not just in the calculation method but also in my update method for starting the landscapeViewController. Now it works, awesome!